# OpenID logon didn't work when using Firefox

Tags: support, firefox, login

I installed Firefox V3.6.3 on WinXP.

When I try to logon to StackOverFlow with my OpenID, I can't logon.
I can logon via IE successfully.

Is there any special configuration which need to be enabled for Firefox?

Comment: Define "failed" please.

Comment: fixed the issue via "Tools > Options > Advanced > Network > Offline Storage (Cache): “Clear Now”"

Comment: I have the same Problem using latest firefox-version (14.0.1) if I try to login to Stackoverflow using Stackexchange-Account. I already tried cleaning the cache but after that logging into my account didn`t work either. Logging in using IE doesn´t cause me trouble. Here is what I did: - coming to stackoverflow.com - select login - clicking log in with StackExcange - 3 dots appear and sign-on fields doesn´t appaer (loading continous endlessly)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the standard clearing of your cache and restarting the browser? Were you able to get it to work on another browser on the same system?

Comment: @Josh K,

After clean the cache, it works well now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite developer response, "Works fine on my machine".